# End file with no empty line for a specific kind of extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

Usually for my codes I need to put an line in the end of the file.

But for a specific kind of extension that I created by the name `.cub` it can´t have this new empty line.
How can I set this in the json setting of Visual Studio?

I tryied this:

```
"[*.cub]": {
    "files.insertFinalNewline": false,
}
```

But it didn´t work.

In my settings I have a `"files.insertFinalNewline": true,`, because for my other files I need an empty end line.

I´ve tryied to change the .editorconfig but it didn´t work either:

```
root = true

[*]
indent_style = tab
indent_size = 4
charset = utf-8
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
insert_final_newline = true

[*.cub]
insert_final_newline = false
```

I tried with and without this command in [*] option:

```
insert_final_newline = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
"[*.cub]": {
  "files.insertFinalNewline": false,
}
```

use this (assuming "cub" is your language identifier):

```
"[cub]": {
  "files.insertFinalNewline": false,
}
```